# Error when load file .dat in matlab

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, speech, matlab-load

I have problem when I try to load file .dat in Matlab.
My file .dat about speech data:

```
% Read data file "orig.dat" with sampling rate of 8 kHz
% create an example sound
fs=8000;
t=0:1/fs:3;
x = 1*sin(2*pi*4*t)+0.25* sin(2*pi*560*t);
% play it back
%sound(x, 8000);
wavwrite(x,fs,16,'test56.wav');
y=wavread('test56.wav')
save y.dat y
load y.dat
```

There is a error:

> ??? Error using ==> load Number of columns on line 1 of ASCII file C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\bin\doan\y.dat
>   must be the same as previous lines.
>   Error in ==> twosubband at 8 load y.dat; % Load speech data

I don't understand.
Help me fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` expects a file in its own data format. Try saving `y` as `y.mat` instead of `y.dat`. 
That is, replace `y.dat` in both the line where you save and the line where you load by `y.mat`.

That should do the trick.